# Mysql sum of two alias_column not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables **Documents** and **poi_data**. Documents contains two types of forms **ETP** and **FP10**. I want to count both type of forms based on numbers and sum of two alias shown in below query. Unfortunately its not working.

```
Document Table (id,title ,type ,status)
poi_data Table (poi_id, doc_id, form_number, status)

SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN documents.title LIKE '%ETP%' THEN poi_data.form_number END) AS form_count_one,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN documents.title LIKE '%FP10%' THEN poi_data.form_number END) AS form_count_two, 
SUM(form_count_one + form_count_two) as total_form_count FROM poi_data 
LEFT JOIN documents ON (poi_data.doc_id = documents.id AND documents.status = 1) 
WHERE poi_data.pid = 781 AND poi_data.poi_id = 8
```

Comment: You can't use the alias name in the same select.

Comment: @dipesh modi   use sum(col_name, col_name)

Comment: @MohitKumar I've tried this but not working : SUM (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN documents.title LIKE '%ETP%' THEN poi_data.form_number END) 
+ COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN documents.title LIKE '%FP10%' THEN poi_data.form_number END)) as total_form_count

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 

(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN documents.title LIKE '%ETP%' THEN poi_data.form_number END) +
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN documents.title LIKE '%FP10%' THEN poi_data.form_number END) AS total_form_count FROM poi_data 
LEFT JOIN documents ON (poi_data.doc_id = documents.id AND documents.status = 1) 
WHERE poi_data.pid = 781 AND poi_data.poi_id = 8
```

You dont need to use SUM because you just want count not the average or what. And then simply ad them using '+'

Answer (score 0):

Just use a subquery:

```
SELECT form_count_one, form_count_two
       (form_count_one + form_count_two) as total_form_count 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN d.title LIKE '%ETP%' THEN pd.form_number END) AS form_count_one,
             COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN d.title LIKE '%FP10%' THEN pd.form_number END) AS form_count_two 
      FROM poi_data pd LEFT JOIN
           documents d
           ON pd.doc_id = d.id AND d.status = 1
      WHERE pd.pid = 781 AND pd.poi_id = 8
     ) d
```

Answer (score -2):

It should be like

```
select SUM(form_count_one + form_count_two) as total_form_count from (SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN documents.title LIKE '%ETP%' THEN poi_data.form_number END) AS form_count_one,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN documents.title LIKE '%FP10%' THEN poi_data.form_number END) AS form_count_two, 
 FROM poi_data 
LEFT JOIN documents ON (poi_data.doc_id = documents.id AND documents.status = 1) 
WHERE poi_data.pid = 781 AND poi_data.poi_id = 8)alias_name
```

Comment: This will show error Unknown column in 'field list'

Comment: Provide me DDL and Test Data